# Quick question: Map being smooth vs Graph being submanifold of the product space

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is $f:X\rightarrow Y$ smooth if and only if the graph $\Gamma_f$ is a closed submanifold of $X\times Y$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I guess not. Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be $f(x)=x^{1/3}$. The graph is a closed submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$. However the map is not smooth.